# How to make Nginx be aware of Rails code changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

If I serve my application using 'Rails s' whenever the code of the application changes the served app changes too. Now I am using Nginx and passenger, how do I replicate this behaviour, at least on the development environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually want to reload Passenger, not nginx.  Create a `tmp/restart.txt` file under your Rails app root directory.  To reload, `touch tmp/restart.txt`.  Passenger will notice the file change and reload.

Comment: That is what I want to avoid. It takes about 3-4 seconds to load the app, because it has to connect to a database. Maybe passenger or nginx  has some option to reload the app whenever there are changes, as they are when you do 'rails s' that way i don't have to wait.

Comment: Oh, autoreload... you may be able to achieve that by setting `rails_env development` in the server block of the nginx configuration where you configure Passenger.  Not sure, though -- I've never done that before.